# How can I make distributed installs generate unique SKUs?

Tags: bash, uuid, sku

I have a open source application github.com/fredzannarbor/pagekicker-community that creates sequential SKUs for each individual product (book) that it builds.  SKUs are currently generated using a simple minded bash file increment.

```
sku=`tail -1 < "$LOCAL_DATA""SKUs/sku_list"`
echo "sku" $sku
```

This was fine when I was the only one running the software, but now that it is being used by others, I do not want SKU collisions to be possible.  SKUs should each have a unique "root" by default, i.e. each installation of the software should create unique SKUs that do not conflict with SKUs created by other installations of the software.  I can't guarantee that any given installation will publish or want to publish its SKUs to a central database.

I don't want to use uuids because there is value in having the SKUs from any given installation be sequential.  I suppose each installation could generate a separate uuid and truncate it, e.g. a62351sdg234... truncated to a62351{SKU}.  But then the roots wouldn't truly be unique--the shorter the root, the more the risk of collision.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunately no answers so far, would be interested to see if there will be in future.